# How to control one object with two pivot points

Tags: transforms, constraints, parent

I am trying to parent two empties to control the extremity of the object as pivot point

[image]

as you can see it works fine for the first one
(the object and the other pivot point are affected, which is what I want)

[image]

But I can't parent back the right empty to the left empty (error message "parent loop")
[image]

Any idea how to achieve this kind of empty controller?

(left empty control relatively to it's position, the rotation of the part and the position/rotation of the right empty. Right empty control, relatively to it's position, the rotation of the part and the position/rotation of the left empty)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use Active element as pivot point.

1. Parent *both* empties to your object
2. Set *Pivot point > Active element*
3. Select your object *and then* the empty you want to pivot around

[image]

Comment: Ok, now I am currious to know if there is a work around to make a parent loop possible